# End in for loop Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print a string with the same character repeated once right after it.  For example, if the input is "hello", the program would output "hheelllloo".  The code

```
for i in "hello":
  print(i, end=i)
```

works, but I suppose I just do not understand it.  I would expect this to give the same output as:

```
for i in "hello":
  print(i + i)
```

Could anyone explain how the top code works?

Comment: A better example might be to replace the `end=i` with `end="_"` so you can visualize what it is doing.

Answer (score 4):

The default value of `end` is a newline. So the second option is equivalent to:

```
for i in "hello":
  print(i + i, end='\n')
```

You could do something like the second one with

```
for i in "hello":
  print(i + i, end='')
```

since this explicitly sets `end` to the empty string so it won't print anything extra.

Answer (score 2):

`print(x)` will append a newline character to the end of the string it prints.

One way to get rid of that is by setting `end=''` to have it append an empty string (equivalent to not appending anything at all) instead:

```
for i in "hello":
  print(i + i, end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers get to this point kind of circuitously, but the basic idea is that the default value for "end" is a newline, so each time you run through the loop it will print a newline and each successive iteration gets printed on a new line. By changing end to "end=i" or "i+i, end=''", you override this default and print each run of the loop on the same line.